# Change default application install language

Tags: windows, windows-10, localization

My newly downloaded and installed VLC player has my country language as default. I must manually set it to show user interface in English. How to make default application language English?

Comment: Change the language of Windows, VLC obviously, respects the chosen language pack currently selected

Comment: If Asker could indicate if a Solution/ Partial Solution, & from what Language(s), especially other than resetting OS Language/Region, has been found, and for which OS version(s) & VLC versions, and if so how to implement, and if the Solution/ Partial Solution is known to extend to other VLC operations, such as VLC zip files, and VLC Settings/ Controls, would be appreciated c12/2020. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set your location to somewhere like the US or UK. Go to your Control Panel and type in the search bar above `region` and launch the applet Region.

On the tab 'Location', select a country like the US, and okay this change. You may need to restart your machine.

If it didn't work, you may need to change the whole region format, that is found in the 'Format' tab, and select 'English (United States)' or similar.